# What is this (in a with statement)? Is it a variable, or something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.x. Could someone please explain to me what `file` in the below block of code is?

```
with open(filename, "a") as file:
    file.write("Hello world")
    print(file) #I added this line to try to understand what 'file' is.
```

When I ran the above code, `print(file)` produced this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Class_A.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I don't understand this. I can see that it's related to the with statement, but it doesn't really look like a variable.

So what is `file`? Is it a variable, or something else? If it is a variable, what data type is it?

Comment: It *is* a variable and it stores a `TextIOWrapper` object. How is that "nothing"?

Comment: Why doesn't it look like a variable? Why doesn't it store anything? Why do you think it is not a variable? It's unclear from your question where the confusion lies.

Comment: The documentation is freely available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: 'put on hold as unclear what you're asking...' - I changed my post a few hours ago to make clear what I'm asking.

Comment: It was clear enough that two of us, at least, have managed to answer it usefully and concisely.  Hey, folks, just because *you* don't understand it doesn't mean it isn't clear to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `file` is a variable, referencing whatever the context manager produced by `open()` returned. It happens to be the same object. In other words, `file` references a file object.

You could also have done this, to the same effect here:

```
file = open(filename, "a")
try:
    file.write("Hello world")
finally:
    file.close()
```

so the file is automatically closed. That's because file objects are *context managers*; they support the [context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers). Technically speaking, the `with context_manager as <name>` target variable is bound to the the return value of `context_manager.__enter__()`, but a file object returns itself from that method, and the `file.__exit__()` method closes the file. See the [`with` compound statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Now, when you *print* an object that doesn't have a string representation, it'll print using the `repr()` function:

```
>>> repr(open('/dev/null'))
"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"
>>> print(repr(open('/dev/null')))
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

so yes, this is just another object, one with a custom, helpful representation. File objects implement the [`object.__repr__()` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) to produce this:

```
>>> open('/dev/null').__repr__()
"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"
```

The name of the file object may also be confusing here. That's because file objects in Python are part of a series of objects defined by the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html); a [`TextIOWrapper` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) wraps a *buffer* (here a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader), which in turn will wrap the raw, binary file object in the form of a [`FileIO` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO):

```
>>> devnull = open('/dev/null', 'r')
>>> devnull
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/dev/null' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> devnull.buffer
<_io.BufferedReader name='/dev/null'>
>>> devnull.buffer.raw
<_io.FileIO name='/dev/null' mode='rb' closefd=True>
```

This is all just tech detail you don't normally need to worry about. Each object performs a specific function, and someone needing to do more advanced I/O wrangling can mix and match these.

Comment: So `file` is a variable which acts as a context manager?

Comment: `file` is name, referencing an object that acts as a context manager.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: There is a distinction between *names* (variables), and the stuff they reference, *objects*. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html for a good explanation of what that means.

Comment: Okay. But what about the data type of the variable? I thought that all variables have data types, so what data type is it?

Comment: @Kaiylar `_io.TextIOWrapper`. Yes, that's a type.

Comment: @Kaiylar: it is a `TextIOWrapper` object. It is not an integer, or a string, or a list, it is an object from the `io` library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So `TextIOWrapper` is the data type of the variable `file`?

Comment: @Kaiylar: yes, `file` references an object that is an instance of the `TextIOWrapper` class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is `_io.` part of the data type? So is it `TextIOWrapper` or `_io.TextIOWrapper`?

Comment: @Kaiylar: `_io` is the (internal) module the class is part of. Just like `datetime.date` is a class in the `datetime` module.

Comment: Okay. I made this question because I'm doing school work, and I need to identify all of the variables which I'll be using to create a program. Would I need to refer to this `file` thingy, or should I not? If I do need to, then how can I simply state its purpose?

Comment: @Kaiylar: Just state that `file` is the open file object to which you are writing. There isn't much more to say about that in the context of your program.

Comment: And I should say that '`TextIOWrapper` is file's data type'?

Comment: @Kaiylar: In the context of your homework, just call it a *file object*. There is no need to go into the implementation details of Python 3 I/O here. That's the datatype, a file object.

Comment: Should I just not include it?

Comment: @Kaiylar: I don't know what your homework looks like. But if you are using `file` in your program, then just identify it as I already showed you. Your teacher will **not** expect you to understand everything about the complexities of the `io` module. It is a file object, plain and simple.

Answer (score 4):

That's the text representation of an object when it doesn't have its own `__repr__` or `__str__`.  `file` is a variable which points to an object of that was created in the with statement.

Answer (score 3):

It is the object that is returned by the `open(filename, "a")` context manager call. The `_io.TextIOWrapper` is a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) that you can do things with like read, write, seek, and close.

When you do this:

```
with thing1 as thing2:
```

The method `thing1.__enter__` gets called, and whatever it returns gets assigned to the variable/name `thing2`.

So yes, in your example `file` is indeed a variable that has been assigned to whatever object has been returned by the `with` context manager. In this case it is a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object. This is why when you do:

```
print(file)
```

You get:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Class_A.txt' mode='a' encoding='cp1252'>
```

...which is just the string representation of that kind of object.

You can manually get the same object this way:

```
file = open(filename, "a").__enter__()
print(file) # same file-like object you were getting before
file.write('a line') # do stuff with it
file.close() # close it
```

Note that the object returned by `open(filename, "a").__enter__()` is the same object you would get from `open(filename, "a")`. This is because the `__enter__()` method of the `_io.TextIOWrapper` object just returns `self`. However, this is not always the case with other objects.

If you find all of this confusing I suggest reading up a bit more about the [`with statement`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).